# How to do a PCA when two subject groups may have different solutions?

Tags: pca

I have two subject groups--one received a drug treatment and the other didn't. We collected a lot of behavioral observations on all the subjects. For the purposes of running stats, I want to reduce the number of behaviors using PCA.

Preliminary analysis reveals some of the behaviors are affected by the drug treatment so the drug treatment subjects behave differently than the controls for some behaviors..so how do I run a PCA accounting for the fact that the principal components/loadings might be different for the treated subjects and un-treated subjects?

Comment: Your question is potentially good (and not new here) but is too reticent to be answered. _What do you want_ your PCs to reflect? Plese think in terms of various group heterogeneities (such as Simpson's paradox etc). Imagine you have just 2 features and want to reduce them to one PC. But you have 2 or more different groups, ellipses, clouds of data points. Draw different possible juxtapositions/superpositions and different orientations of the ellipses. What would be your yearnings from the resultant PC as you contemplate such pics?

Answer (score 3):

You would not want to run PCA separately on both datasets, since the resulting PCA dimensions would not be comparable.

Since actually you want to know how to describe both datasets with least possible dimensions, you will combine both datasets  and perform a single PCA on the combined dataset.

Yet a single PCA dimension will be a linear combination of all input dimensions therefore you can not effectively exclude dimensions, but rather "summarize" your data.

Comment: This answer is a bit short to be good. `you will combine both datasets` The main issue is how to combine, what possible transforms could be helpful at that. You haven't discussed any variants.

Comment: You are right, the answer is rather short and possibly not sufficient. Feel free to add a comprehensive answer and I will upvote it directly.